# Using typing module in docstring

Tags: python, pycharm, typing, docstring

Suppose I have a function with a docstring where I declare the return type as a tuple with two strings:

```
def foo():
    """
    Returns:
        Tuple[str, str]: Tuple of first name and last name
    """
```

Am I supposed to import `Tuple` from `typing` if I don't use it anywhere except for in docstrings?

Comment: Docstrings are not executable (unless you use `doctest`, but even then anything not preceded by `>>>` is ignored), and so do not need imports. You would need an import if you actually type the function: `def foo() -> Tuple[str, str]:` Then again, I don't see the point of saying "returns a tuple" twice, once in typing syntax and once in English, next to each other, in a docstring.

Comment: What tool are you using that reads the information from the docstring? PyCharm? Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: Also see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-syntax-for-docstrings.html; it is a legacy format, and not specificly supporting PEP 484 type hints.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am indeed using PyCharm and was attempting to switch to using Google's Python Docstring guidelines. Thank you for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: Then you are not actually using `typing`, no imports needed. Do you have specific requirements that say you must adhere to Google's styleguide? If not, I'd just use type hints properly and not bother with putting that info in the docstring.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm pretty much free to pick whatever style I like, I'm just figuring out a good basis to stand on :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm's docstring support for type hints does not actually use `typing`. You do not need to import the module.

The `typing` module is only there to support the fact that annotations are executed at runtime; for a statement starting with `def foo() -> Tuple[str, str]:`, Python will actually evaluate the expression `Tuple[str, str]` so expects to be able to resolve the names. (As of Python 3.7 you can disable (or rather, *postpone*) the evaluation with `from __future__ import annotations`).

But a docstring is not evaluated, normally, and is not expected to be able to contain runnable Python code.

Unless you have a hard requirement to put the type info in the docstring, I'd stick with *actual annotations*:

```
from typing import Tuple


# type aliases
firstname = str
lastname = str


def foo() -> Tuple[firstname, lastname]:
    """Descriptive line documenting this function's purpose"""
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Docstrings are just comments. They are ignored by the interpreter. So, don't import it, otherwise code checking tools (eg. `pylint`) will complain about unused imports.

However, it would probably be better to use *backticks* inside your docstring for parts that are actual code. eg

```
"""
Returns:
    `Tuple[str, str]`: Tuple of first name and last name
"""
```

That way, doc-generation tools know that it's actual code, and can format it properly.